# updating value of an object variable in smarty in the template

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to modify a template in a simple manner, not rewrite the underlying code.  I realize normally object assignment is not done in the template, but is it possible?

I want something like this:

```
{if $product->available_now == "XXX001"}
    {assign var="product->available_now" value={"YYY123"}}
{/if}
```

I want to read the object variable $product->available_now and, based on its contents, update it to something else for use later down in the template.

Everything I try ends up with either a blank screen or else (as is the case with my code above) an unchanged variable.

FYI: this is for use with prestashop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
{if $product->available_now == "XXX001"}
    {assign var=product->available_now value="YYY123"}
{/if}
```

Comment: Lol... so I was that close?  After days without an answer, I moved on to a different method.  I'm not going to mess with it now so I'm just going to assume your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I must confess that I have not tested it but it has to be the error you made, as this is the correct way to assign a value to a variable!